# ExtJS 4.1 or general Javascript HTTP_Authorization Function

Tags: javascript, http-headers, extjs4, http-authentication

When making a request using `curl --basic --user someuser:somepass http://someurl/` it append a header like this: `Authorization: Basic Y2FsaWRvZzpmMDBmM2IwMg==`. This is, of course,

> Basic access authentication is a method for a web browser or other client program to provide a user name and password when making a request. Before transmission, the user name is appended with a colon and concatenated with the password. The resulting string is encoded with the Base64 algorithm and transmitted in the HTTP header and decoded by the receiver, resulting in the colon-separated user name and password string. Basic access authentication was originally defined in 1996 by RFC 1945 [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication][1]  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

I'm looking for a way to have all my ExtJS 4.1 Ext.data.proxy.Rest proxies add this to all requests. It seems like a simple task, but I can find no documentation on it. By the way, I do know how to add headers to proxies generally through `headers: {'X_MyHeader':'somevalue'}` property. I just do not know how to tell Ext to do it globally for the current username/password.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution for applying OAuth tokens to my Ext.data.proxy.Rest proxies and couldn't find any info about it. Quite shocked there is nothing out there about how to do this. Makes me think I'm going about it the wrong way. Anyway heres what I've come up with to achieve this.

Override `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax` and keep a static variable so it applies to all proxies. Then merge the set authHeader with the current list of headers so you can still customise per proxy.

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.proxy.Ajax, {

    statics: {
        authHeader: undefined,
    },

    /**
     * @cfg {Object} headers
     * Any headers to add to the Ajax request. Defaults to undefined.
     */

    doRequest: function(operation, callback, scope) {
        var writer  = this.getWriter(),
            request = this.buildRequest(operation, callback, scope);

        if (operation.allowWrite()) {
            request = writer.write(request);
        }
        console.log(this.headers);
        Ext.apply(request, {
            headers       : Ext.apply(this.headers, Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.authHeader) || Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.authHeader,
            timeout       : this.timeout,
            scope         : this,
            callback      : this.createRequestCallback(request, operation, callback, scope),
            method        : this.getMethod(request),
            disableCaching: false // explicitly set it to false, ServerProxy handles caching
        });

        Ext.Ajax.request(request);

        return request;
    }
});
```

Then I look for my token in local storage, if it's there set it globally, otherwise prompt for a login.

```
MyApp.model.AuthToken.load(1, {
    callback: function(record) {
        // If we don't have anything in local storage for the user, show the login box.
        if (record.get('access_token') == '') {
            var window = Ext.create('MyApp.view.Login');
            window.show();
        } else {
            Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.authHeader = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + record.get('access_token') };
        }
    }
});
```

There should be some extra logic in there for handling token expiry and refresh requests, but you get the idea!